# Azure Kubernetes Service to Log Analytics Workspace - duplicated metrics ContainerInsights and LogManagement

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I have AKS with enabled Container Insights. Everything configured according to documentation. Lately I have noticed, that:

[image: AKS Query]

That is the amount of logs that are ingested into Log Analytics Workspace. I find it troubling, that LogManagement and ContainerInsights are so similar, they partially contain the same metrics. I am afraid that I am paying for some ingestion twice.

Am I missing something? I am aware of `container-azm-ms-agentconfig` ConfigMap, but I see no solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose I found an answer. It turns out to be just a coincidence - that the amount for ContainerInsights and LogManagement look alike. The best place to reason about Log Analytics ingestion is Log Analytics Workspace Insights. It shows an actual ingestion sources. The logs in query view may look duplicated (Insights Metrics), but they are actually ingested once.